# Codename one Simulators sizes do not fit within the window

Tags: codenameone

While developing app with codename one with Netbeans IDE, I was running into this issue where the simulators were not usable except iphone 3.  If I choose the simulator to be iPhone 5 or 6 or 6 plus, the simulator is so huge and only part of it appears on the screen and I couldn't even scroll.

Is there anyway to make the simulator to fit within the window sizes?  I tried on Mac and Windows and I experienced the same result.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the `Scrollable` option under the `Simulalator` menu. It's on by default since some artifacts might appear during scaling but for large skins there is no alternative.